# How fetch the JSON value on condition

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON like:

```
{
   "data":{
      "mapping":[
         {
            "erp":"SYMIX",
            "plant":"RY1",
            "region":"NA"
         },
         {
            "erp":"SAP",
            "plant":"EXM",
            "region":"ASIA"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I get a value of plant on that basis I want to get the value of erp.
like if I get RY1 SYMIX needs to be fetch. How can I achieve this using Java

Comment: what json library are you using?

Comment: You need to create one pojo class for mapping and then create list of that class with JSON values, then you can easily get object from list

Comment: @RakeshGR I am using org.JSON

Answer (score 1):

It could be easy done using jayway library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The example:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

public class TestJson {
 private static final String JSON = "{\"data\":{\"mapping\":[{\"erp\":\"SYMIX\",\"plant\":\"RY1\",\"region\":\"NA\"},{\"erp\":\"SAP\",\"plant\":\"EXM\",\"region\":\"ASIA\"}]}}";

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     String erp = getErp("RY1");
     System.out.println(erp);
 }

 private static String getErp(String plant) {
     List<String> values = JsonPath.read(JSON, String.format("$.data.mapping.[?(@.plant==%s)].erp", plant));
     return values.isEmpty() ? null : values.get(0);
 }
}
```

The output is: `SYMIX`

---

**UPDATED:**

Ok, here version to read from file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

public class TestJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String pathToFile = "file.json";
        String plant = "RY1";

        File file = openFile(pathToFile);
        String erp = readErpFromFile(file, plant);
        System.out.println("Erp: " + erp);
    }

    private static String readErpFromFile(File file, String plant) throws Exception {
        List<String> values = JsonPath.read(file, String.format("$.data.mapping.[?(@.plant==%s)].erp", plant));
        return values.isEmpty() ? null : values.get(0);
    }

    private static File openFile(String strPath) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(strPath);
        System.out.println("Trying to read file: " + path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        return path.toFile();
    }
}
```

Just replace "file.json" string to path of your file.

Comment: It works fine. . .Mine JSON is in file so how can I convert it into String variable

Answer (score 0):

Okay...I have gone for a pretty straight forward approach.
Try this:

```
public static Object searchArrayofObjects(JSONArray array, String searchByKey, String resultKey, Object searchObject) throws JSONException
{
    Object result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject innerObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
        if (innerObject.has(searchByKey) && innerObject.get(searchByKey).equals(searchObject))
        {
            result = innerObject.has(resultKey) ? innerObject.get(resultKey) : null;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now call searchArrayofObjects(mapping,"plant","erp","RY1") and it should return "SYMIX".

I have obviouly made it a little generic. But this is the general approach I should think.